# How to get a specific future date in date picker

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have some data comprising startdate and enddate.

When I edit that data, I want to only allow future dates in enddate datepicker, but that has to be one day greater than the startdate.

For Example: If startdate = 01/05/2020, then I want enddate to be 01/06/2020 or greater than that in datepicker.

I tried that with a function naming `getNextDayToStartDate()` but I know I am doing something wrong.

Thanks.

Please see the code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dtnlyc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  onEditData(data): void {
    var newdate = this.getNextDayToStartDate(data.startDate);
    this.editData = {
      Name: data.Name,
      startDate: this.getDate(data.startDate),
      endDate: newdate
    }
    this.editDataDialog = true;
  }
```

Your function to add a day returns a value, yet you continue with the original value. Capturing the returnvalue and using that, solves the issue.

Small sidenote: momentjs is a rather usefull thing for working with dates :) Might want to look in to that ;)

Comment: But when I am entering start dates of 2019, it starts disabling the dates of 2020. Please have a look at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dtnlyc

Comment: new Date(startDate) is causing the startDate to change
11/20/2019 -> 2019-11-19 (date formatting with culture differences)
nextDay.toISOString().split('T')[0] -> again realy strange things happening because of culture differences causing this date to become 2020-01-21
try momentjs

Answer (score 0):

Add editData.startDate to you method call in your html, that will fix it!

```
<input type="date" [min]="getNextDayToStartDate(editData.startDate)" [(ngModel)]="editData.endDate">
```