# When restricting date in datepicker, it restricts the dates of next year

Tags: angular

This is in reference to [How to get a specific future date in date picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59628523/how-to-get-a-specific-future-date-in-date-picker/)

I changed the code acc. to the answer:

```
onEditData(data): void {
    var newdate = this.getNextDayToStartDate(data.startDate);
    this.editData = {
      Name: data.Name,
      startDate: this.getDate(data.startDate),
      endDate: newdate
    }
    this.editDataDialog = true;
  }
```

But when I select a startdate of year 2019, in enddate date picker it restricts date of year 2020. Please have a look: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dtnlyc

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refactor the following block of code:

```
getNextDayToStartDate(startDate): string {
  startDate = new Date(startDate);
  const nextDay = new Date();
  nextDay.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);
  console.log(nextDay)
  return nextDay.toISOString().split('T')[0];
}
```

`const next day = new Date();` You are getting the current date and setting day based on the start date. Remember the `new Date()` gives you the year 2020. The `setDate()` method sets the day of the month. It does not change year or month.

Try the following:

```
getNextDayToStartDate(startDate): string {
  const nextDay = new Date(startDate);
  nextDay.setDate(nextDay.getDate() + 1);
  return nextDay.toISOString().split('T')[0];
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works! And thanks for clearing the concept. :)